# Library with custom fields. How this is done?

Tags: library

How this is done? Can this be Visual Studio bug? Or what?

I have made my own solution, which based on older version of SharePoint project. So, I haven't made this and I cannot ask how this is made. It works, but I don't understand why it works. And I want to know.

I know that EditDlg.htm, FileDlg.htm and so on, are missing.
I have defined normally fields in Schema.xml file but this is intersting how this is made without Schema.xml. There is only Elements.xml file.

I have defined fields, content type and I have created library instance. Like old version have:

**Content type**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <!-- Parent ContentType: Document (0x0101) -->
<ContentType ID="0x01010021BB0D1156254772BE97C1D485D39E59"
           Name="Reports"
           Group="EBIC"
           Description="This Content Type is used for EBIC Report Library"
           Inherits="FALSE"
           Version="0">
<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Title" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" />
  <FieldRef ID="{112b7a31-07de-415c-88c3-2762983c9d0d}" Name="EBICDescription" DisplayName="Description" Sealed="TRUE"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{38900A0D-4BF4-434C-B130-12D959E56E1D}" Name="ReportAuthorizedUserGroup" DisplayName="Authorized User/Group" Sealed="TRUE"/>
</FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
</Elements>
```

**Library instance**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="Reporting Service Reports"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="101"
                FeatureId="00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101"
                Url="Lists/Reports"
                Description="Manage Reporting Service Reports">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

However end result do not match and I can't find reason why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you post the source Library Schema? There must be some code or xml declaration which added the Content type to Library but your version is missing that..

Comment: Well, that is funny part... There is no schema.xml file. That's why I'm confused. How it can work without it. Or does Visual Studio somehow bugs? Is it possible?

Comment: Nop not possible, can you see if there are any Feature Event Receivers attached

Comment: Yes, thank you! It was Event Receiver. Dam I'm stupid... :D

Comment: Great, I will post my comment as answer so you can mark it to close the Question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be Feature Event Receiver which will be adding the Content Type programmatically to the Library, please have a look if there is any

Answer (score 0):

We covered this at the International SharePoint Conference a few years back. Grab the code from [CodePlex](http://spkbase.codeplex.com/). Look for the ListInstances feature in the ISC.KBase.Advanced release.